# Is there a way to turn on Chrome Autofill for non-technical users?

Tags: google-chrome, auto-form-fill

We're trying to make it easier for some senior users to fill out applications and AUTOFILL can help them. Is there a way they could easily turn on AUTOFILL - without having to go through and adjust all the Chrome settings manually? Thanks.

Comment: All of what chrome settings? Auto fill is already on by default. It’s one option.